# post form to url and database or url

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a form that I host . To meet my clients needs I must post to specific url .I wuld like to be able to post to a dattabase or google spreadsheet at the same time so I can track results

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is log the data in the database, and then provide a feed for the Google Spreadsheet.

Google Docs Spreadsheets are capable of loading various formats of data over HTTP.  You can provide a feed of that data, and the spreadsheet will automatically update as new data is available.

For example, in your spreadsheet:

```
=importHTML("http://www.google.com/search?q=define:live", "list", 1)
```

Example from:  http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/09/google-spreadsheets-lets-you-import.html